# CoreMotion Accelerometer iPhone 5 vs. iPod (5the Gen)

Tags: ios7, accelerometer, core-motion

I'm executing the following code on both an iPhone 5 and iPod (5th Gen) running iOS 7.0.4.  On the iPhone the update is near-real time, while on the iPod there is a significant delay.  What am I doing wrong to cause this difference?  Shouldn't they both be the same???

```
motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval  = 1.0/20.0; // Update at 20Hz
if (motionManager.accelerometerAvailable) {
    NSLog(@"Accelerometer avaliable");
    queue = [NSOperationQueue currentQueue];
    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:queue
                                        withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                                            CMAcceleration useracceleration = accelerometerData.userAcceleration;
                                            xLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", useracceleration.x];
                                            xBar.progress = ABS(useracceleration.x);

                                            yLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", useracceleration.y];
                                            yBar.progress = ABS(useracceleration.y);

                                            zLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", useracceleration.z];
                                            zBar.progress = ABS(useracceleration.z);

                                            force = (bodymass * sqrt((pow(useracceleration.x,2) + pow(useracceleration.y,2) + pow(useracceleration.z,2))));



                                            forceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", force];
                                            forceBar.progress = ABS(force);

                                        }];


}
```

Please help...I want this code to be able to run accurately on both devices.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `significant delay`?

Comment: Also note that benchmarks show that the iPod touch 5th Gen has the same computing power as around an *iPhone 4S*

Comment: Peter M...the iPod is taking about a second or longer to show any change if the force calculation.  While the iPhone 5 (not 5s...typo) is updating within milliseconds.

Comment: I did make a couple of changes that have seemed to help the iPod performance:

I replaced the line:
        queue = [NSOperationsQueue currentQueue];
with
        queue = [[NSOperationsQueue alloc]init];

I also inserted:
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //all the UI stuff in here
        }

This greatly improved the performance, but still not as good as I see on the iPhone.  

Questions:  1)are these changes correct in getting the UI updated properly? 2) why did it work on the iPhone without these changes?

Thanks.